# Selenium DevTools should log ALL but only logs ERROR and VERBOSE, how come?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently working on a Selenium project and we've just updated to the most recent version of Selenium.
Now I wanted to output the result of my console.log()s into the Java console when executing the Selenium test but it seems like it's only logging some specific things.

Code:

```
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
final DevTools devTools = webDriver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
devTools.send(Log.enable());
devTools.addListener(Log.entryAdded(), logEntry -> {
    LOG.info("[{}]: {}", logEntry.getLevel().toString().toUpperCase(), logEntry.getText());
});
```

Though while my output in the Chrome window of the test contains `VERBOSE` messages, console.log()s and two kinds of errors (one `HTTP 500` error and one Angular error for something I've done wrong), the only things that actually end up in my Java console are the `VERBOSE` messages and the `HTTP 500` error. Not even the Angular errors but definitely none of the console.log()s.

How do I fix that?

Comment: I think this shows you how to capture the JS Exceptions: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#listen-to-js-exceptions  Maybe the "console.log()s" you're talking about come from the JS?

Comment: It has nothing to do with JS but I've actually found the solution when researching about the stuff you pointed me at, so thanks. :D (The solution was to use devTools.send(Runtime.enable)